# How to remove Node-module folder and Create-React-App project?

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

Recently, I felt my computer was slowing down. 
So, I found why my computer is slowing down.
The reason is Node-module and Create-React-App project folder!
So I deleted those folder. but my window popup me to "You need admin authority when you delete Node_module or CRA"

So I clicked "continue" But this pop up message is Keep coming out!

I want delete those file anyway
please help me.(I'm using window10)

Comment: You can use your terminal to delete node_modules folder. Go to your folder directory location in the terminal and try `sudo rm -rf node_modules`. `sudo` will help give you the super user privilege you need to delete.

Comment: I'm using window. I don't have a Linux are you meaning wsl?

Answer (score 1):

If you use WSL you can try

```
sudo rm -rf node_modules
```

Or open your cmd as administrator and

```
rmdir /S node_modules
```